# How to set CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES in CMakeLists depending on debug or release configuration?

Tags: macos, cmake

I want to set CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES to "arm64;x86_64" only if in release configuration, and I want to do that in CMakeLists (not on the command line), but I can't figure it out.

I tried:

```
set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>, "", arm64;x86_64)
```

but that fails.

The documentation says that it needs to be set before the `project()` call, which I'm doing.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The documentation you mentioned also doesn't mention the possibility of using generator expressions in the value. Furthermore the fact that you need to set it before `project()` indicates that it's similar to variables like `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, i.e. it's info that is not configuration-dependent. This seems to be impossible to do for multi-configuration generators. Also note this part of the documentation of the var: *"It is intended to be set locally by the user creating a build tree."* Your use case is not the intended one...

Comment: It seems simple enough. When I'm developing/working (running in debug mode), there's no need for it to build both architectures. It should just build for my native machine. But when I'm building for release, it should build for both architectures. The reason I tried the generator expression was that I don't know any other way to find out if the current build is for debug or release. There should be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a regular `if()`, not a generator expression.

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES arm64 x86_64)
endif()
```